# Wanted to use auto sorting with GridView in ASP.Net with VB code

Tags: vb.net, sorting, data-binding, gridview

I am using a Gridview to show data from one table, however usying my below code it's not allowing me to auto sort, I get an error stating "System.Web.HttpException: The GridView 'GridView1' fired event Sorting which wasn't handled"

It should auto sort without the need for me to write code for sorting event, I have made it work but via the ASPX file, but I don't want to use that becuase I would like to change the query to do diffrent filters so I want to do this from the .vb file not .aspx file

Here is my code

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient



Public Class WebForm1
   Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

   Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

      Dim cnnData As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DataTestConnectionString").ConnectionString)
    'Dim adData As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim dsData As New DataSet
    Dim strQry As String

    strQry = "SELECT Student_No, " & _
                    "FName, " & _
                    "MName, " & _
                    "LName, " & _
                    "Phone_No, " & _
                    "Major, " & _
                    "Start_Date, " & _
                    "Status " & _
             "FROM tblStudent"



    Dim adData As New SqlDataAdapter(strQry, cnnData)

    adData.Fill(dsData)
    GridView1.DataSource = dsData

    GridView1.DataBind()



    'cnnData.Close()
    'adData.Dispose()

End Sub

End Class
```

and here is my aspx markup:

```
 <asp:GridView 
         ID="GridView1" 
         runat="server" 
         AllowPaging="True" 
         AllowSorting="True" 
         AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
         DataKeyNames="Student_No" 
         Height="30%" 
         Width="90%"
         CssClass="GridViewCSS"
         PagerStyle-CssClass="GridViewPager" 
         AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="GridViewAlt"
         DataGridViewLinkColumn="Student_No"
         >


  <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="GridViewAlt"></AlternatingRowStyle>


        <Columns>


        <asp:hyperlinkfield 
             DataTextField ="Student_No"
             navigateurl="./studentedit.aspx"            
             headertext="Employee No"
             />

            <asp:BoundField 
                 DataField="Student_No" 
                 HeaderText="Student No" 
                 ReadOnly="True" 
                 SortExpression="Student_No" 
                 FooterStyle-Font-Underline ="true"
                 />


            <asp:BoundField 
                 DataField="FName" 
                 HeaderText="First Name" 
                 ReadOnly="True" 
                 SortExpression="FName" 
                 />

            <asp:BoundField 
                 DataField="MName" 
                 HeaderText="Middle Initial" 
                 ReadOnly="True" 
                 SortExpression="MName" 
                 />

            <asp:BoundField 
                 DataField="LName" 
                 HeaderText="Last Name" 
                 ReadOnly="True" 
                 SortExpression="LName" 
                 />


            <asp:BoundField 
                 DataField="Phone_No" 
                 HeaderText="Phone Number" 
                 ReadOnly="True" 
                 SortExpression="Phone_No" 
                 />

            <asp:BoundField 
                 DataField="Major" 
                 HeaderText="Major" 
                 ReadOnly="True" 
                 SortExpression="Major" 
                 />

            <asp:BoundField 
                 DataField="start_date" 
                 HeaderText="Start Date" 
                 ReadOnly="True" 
                 SortExpression="Start_Date" 
                 />

            <asp:BoundField 
                 DataField="Status" 
                 HeaderText="Status" 
                 ReadOnly="True" 
                 SortExpression="Status" 
                 />

        </Columns>

 <PagerStyle CssClass="GridViewPager"></PagerStyle>
      </asp:GridView
```

Help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your ASP, but I have a little trick for sorting the DataTable itself in VB. As you know, you can't directly sort a datatable. You can, however, sort a dataview. The trick is to create a view of your table, sort the view, then convert your view into a new table.

With the below function you can pass in your datatable, the column name to sort on, and ASC or DESC for ascending or descending. You can remove the "order" parameter from the function if you want and the view will always sort ascending. You can then bind the table to your GrindView. You can also send a string of multiple sortColumns if you want.

Create the function:

```
Public Function SortMyTable(ByVal ds As DataTable,_
     sortColumn As String, order As String) As DataTable

    ' Create a DataView of your original dataset 
    Dim view As New DataView(ds)
    ' Sort your data view.
    view.Sort = sortColumn + " " + order 
    ' Put your dataview into a new datatable
    Dim dt As DataTable = view.ToTable()

    ' Return your newly sorted datatable
    Return dt
End Function
```

Using the function:

```
Dim sortColumn As String = "MyColumnName"
Dim order As String = "ASC"

' Create your dataset
Dim ds As New DataTable
' fill your DataTable

' Use the function to return a new sorted dataset
Dim dt As DataTable = SortMyTable(ds, column, order)
'dt is a new datatable, sorted how you want it.
```

Good luck!

References: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.sort.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Hey You Can also sort your display data by SQL query:

```
trQry = "SELECT Student_No, " & _
                "FName, " & _
                "MName, " & _
                "LName, " & _
                "Phone_No, " & _
                "Major, " & _
                "Start_Date, " & _
                "Status " & _
         "FROM tblStudent **order by FName**"
```

You can sort in any way,,In above I have sort tblstudent according to FName wise.